# Tailwind Variants with container queries breakpoints

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, container-queries, tailwind-variants

I was reading the Tailwind Variants documentations and have an doubt.
at "Responsive variants" we have this example:

```
import { tv } from "tailwind-variants";
 
const button = tv({
  base: "font-semibold text-white py-1 px-3 rounded-full active:opacity-80",
  variants: {
    color: {
      primary: "bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700",
      secondary: "bg-purple-500 hover:bg-purple-700",
      success: "bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700",
    },
    size: {
      small: "py-0 px-2 text-xs",
      medium: "py-1 px-2 text-sm",
      large: "py-1.5 px-3 text-md",
    },
  }
},
{
  responsiveVariants: ['sm', 'md'] // `true` to apply to all screen sizes
});
 
button({
  color: {
    initial: "primary",
    sm: "success",
    md: "secondary",
  },
  size: {
    initial: "small",
    sm: "medium",
    md: "large",
  },
});
 
/**
 * Result: 
 * 
 * font-semibold text-white rounded-full active:opacity-80 bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 sm:bg-green-500 
 * sm:hover:bg-green-700 md:bg-purple-500 md:hover:bg-purple-700 py-0 px-2 text-xs sm:py-1 sm:px-2 sm:text-sm 
 * md:py-1.5 md:px-3 md:text-md
 */
```

BUT

When we use container queries we put @ before the breakpoints ( @sm, @md, @lg ...).

If i'm using a button inside a div that uses '@container' how can i use the container queries breakpoint with tailwind variants?

Maybe replace:
responsiveVariants: ['sm', 'md'] // `true` to apply to all screen sizes
To this:
responsiveVariants: ['@sm', '@md'] // `true` to apply to all screen sizes
?

If i'm using a button inside a div that uses '@container' how can i use the container queries breakpoint with tailwind variants?